# Use of C# 'ref' keyword compared to C++

Tags: c#, c++

I have mainly worked in C++ and I am now using C# at my new job, and after doing some reading on here about the 'ref' keyword and c# value vs reference types I am still finding some confusion with them.

As far as I'm understanding these if you were passing these to a method these would be analogous C++ styles:

**Value types:**

```
public void CSharpFunc(value)
```

and

```
public void CPlusplusFunc(value)
```

**Reference types:**

```
public void CSharpFunc(reference)
```

and

```
public void CPlusPlusFunc(&reference)
```

**'ref' / pointer**

```
public void CSharpFunc(ref bar)
```

and

```
public void CPlusPlus(*bar)
```

Is this a correct analogy?

Comment: The ref/pointer analogy is not a good one IMO. There's no pointer concept at all in C# (I mean, managed C# of course).

Comment: @ken2k OK, but in C# `ref int a` gives you the same ability as `int *a` in c/c++. It lets you change the value of the outer variable inside the function.

Comment: @dvvrd That is incorrect.  Please see my example.

Comment: For at least the C++ code part (I cannot tell if the C# is correct), it would be useful if you used actual valid C++ syntax.

Comment: @weston it's true that both `ref int` and `int *` allow you to simulate "pass by reference", but unlike C, C++ has *real* pass-by-reference baked into the language, and that is `int &`.

Comment: @weston untrue. See Konrad Rudolph answer. Also, you can modified the "value of the outer variable inside the function" without ref, if the type of the value is a reference type.

Comment: @weston: Pointers in both C and C++ are more similar to objects in C# than to `ref`s: With a C||C++-pointer and with a C#-object, you can: Modify the data at the place the pointer/object points at, but you can't overwrite the callers copy of the pointer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is this a correct analogy?

Despite what the other answers say, no. What `ref` means in terms of C++ actually depends on the type. For value types, your assessment is correct (or close enough). For reference types, a more suitable analogy would be a reference-to-pointer:

```
public void CPlusPlus(type*& bar)
```

The whole point about `ref` is that you can *change* the reference being passed in. And you can’t do that in C++ by simply passing a pointer:

```
void f(type* bar) {
    bar = new_address;
}

type* x;
f(x);
```

This code won’t change the caller’s value of `x`. If you had passed `bar` as `type*&`, on the other hand, it *would have* changed the value. That is what `ref` does.

Furthermore, a reference in C# is quite unlike a reference in C++, and much more like a pointer in C++ (in that you can change which object the reference refers to).

Comment: If `type*` is the type `T`, then the `ref` equivilant function would need to have a param type of `T*` or `type**`. Your example shows a function with an argument of plain type `T`.

Comment: @weston Fair enough. But that gets even more confusing because in C++ most people would use `*&` to modify a pointer argument, not `**` (the latter is used quite often in C, though). Unfortunately, OP left out the types in his question altogether, making everything unclear.

Comment: Thank you, I apologize for leaving out *& and **, I should have really included them, but thank you for being able to decipher my example anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

It would be more accurate (though still not *exactly* the same) to swap your "Reference types" and "`ref`" examples.

In C#, a **reference type** is a type that is always accessed internally via a reference to an instance of the type. It is easiest to thing of these as "pointers" in the C++ sense: you allocate memory, run the constructor(s), and get back a value that indirectly refers to the object you want. The difference between C# and C++ here is that in C#, this is a property of the *type*, not of the *variable*. A type is either *always* a reference type or *always* a value type. One effect of this is that you don't have to do anything special to use a reference type (there is no "dereference" operator in managed C# code); the compiler assumes that reference type variable access is indirected. In C++ you would still need to use the `->` operator, because you can have both value and reference variables of the same type (`object x` vs. `object *x`).

The `ref` keyword is used to pass parameters by reference; those parameters can be either a value type (like `int`) or a reference type. While the implementation of the `ref` keyword is ultimately an address-of/pointer-to type operation (exactly as `&` is in C++), `ref` (and `out`) produce a special type of object called a ***managed reference***, which is different from a reference type in that you can have managed references to value types. This is almost exactly the way C++ works: an `int&` is a special type of "reference to an int" that is distinct from `int *`, even though both are basically using pointer indirection to access a variable. Similarly, in C# you can have a `ref Object`, which would be effectively an `object *&`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are mostly correct, (s/*/*& and you're 100% there).  As @weston mentioned, `out` is an additional keyword to be familiar with.  The only cute thing you can do with `ref` is overload a function that's not ref.

```
class Person {
   string Name { get; set; }
   string Address { get; set; }
   int age { get; set; }
}

public void UpdateName(Person p)
{
   if (p == null) 
   {
      return;
   }

   p.Name = "Tom";
}

public void UpdateName(ref Person p)
{
   if (p == null)
   {
      p = new Person();
   }

   p.Name = "Tom";
}
```

Obviously useless, but it does provide for some interesting opportunities (and bad design).  `out` does not provide the same overload functionality.

If you would like 1 for 1, you can always block your code with `unsafe`.